# Efficient way to match two columns that share the same type of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this problem, 'A' and 'B' both store the same kind of data (page numbers). 'Hits_A' is a sum of hits according to 'A' (previous grouping, not shown). I'd like to sum 'Hits_A' based on column 'B', and then relate the values back to the page numbers on column 'A', like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'B': [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 6],
                   'Hits_A': [10, 40, 50, 35, 24, 60, 30]})

tmp = df.drop('A', axis=1)
tmp = tmp.groupby('B').sum().reset_index()
tmp = tmp.rename(columns={'B':'A', 'Hits_A':'Hits_B'})

output = pd.merge(df, tmp, how='left', on='A').drop('B', axis=1)
```

```
print(df)
```

yields

```
   A  B  Hits_A
0  1  3      10
1  2  4      40
2  3  5      50
3  4  2      35
4  5  1      24
5  6  1      60
6  7  6      30
```

```
print(output)
```

yields

```
   A  Hits_A  Hits_B
0  1      10    84.0
1  2      40    35.0
2  3      50    10.0
3  4      35    40.0
4  5      24    50.0
5  6      60    30.0
6  7      30     NaN
```

These are the results I want to replicate in a less janky, cleaner looking manner. I'm not very used to things like lambda functions, and was wondering if this could all be achieved in fewer lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `groupby` and `sum` then `map` the grouped sum to column `A`

```
df['Hits_B'] = df['A'].map(df.groupby('B')['Hits_A'].sum())
```

---

```
   A  B  Hits_A  Hits_B
0  1  3      10    84.0
1  2  4      40    35.0
2  3  5      50    10.0
3  4  2      35    40.0
4  5  1      24    50.0
5  6  1      60    30.0
6  7  6      30     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for!